# How to prove that $\left(\overline{A}\right)'\subset A'$ in a Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

If $E$ is a Hausdorff space, and $A\subset E$ how to prove that $\left(\overline{A}\right)'\subset A'$ ?

> We say that $x\in A'$ if and only if $\forall V\in \mathcal{V}_x,
>  (V\setminus\{x\})\cap A\neq\emptyset$
>
> We say that $x\in \overline{A}$ if and only if $\forall V\in
>  \mathcal{V}_x, V\cap A\neq\emptyset$

So let $x\in \left(\overline{A}\right)' $ then $\forall V\in \mathcal{V}_x, (V\setminus\{x\})\cap \overline{A}\neq \emptyset$

then there exist $y$ such that $y\in V\setminus\{x\}$ and  $y\in \overline{A}$ so $y\in V$ and $\forall W\in \mathcal{V}_y, W\cap A\neq \emptyset$

We have that $E$ is a Hausdorff space so there exist a nbh $V_1$ to $x$ and  $V_2$ for $y$ such that $V_1\cap V_2= \emptyset$

But how we prove that  $(V\setminus\{x\})\cap A\neq \emptyset$

how to continue please

Comment: it is the derived of the closure @DaveL.Renfro have you an idea please

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\overline A = A \cup A'$. Since the derived set of a finite union is the union of the derived sets, we have $\left(\overline A\right)' = A' \cup A''$. Since $A'$ is closed in a $T_1$-space (see [Set of limit points of a subset of a Hausdorff space is closed.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258776/set-of-limit-points-of-a-subset-of-a-hausdorff-space-is-closed)), we have $A''\subseteq A'$ and thus $\left(\overline A\right)'\subseteq A'$.

Comment: here we have directly the equality $\left(\overline{A}\right)'=A'$

Comment: @Vrouvrou: Yes, we have an equality.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is easier to prove the contrapositive: $(A')^c \subset ((\overline{A})')^c$.

Suppose that $x \in (A')^c$, so $x$ is not a limit point of $A$. Therefore there exists $V \in \mathcal V_x$ such that $W = V \setminus \{x\}$ does not intersect $A$. If we can show that $W$ does not intersect $\overline A$ then we're done.

We already know that $W$ does not intersect $A$, so it suffices to show that $W$ does not contain any limit points of $A$.

Note that $\{x\}$ is closed since the space is Hausdorff (see proof below), so $W = V \setminus \{x\} = V \cap (\{x\})^c$ is an intersection of two open sets, hence open. Suppose $y \in W$. If $y$ were a limit point of $A$, then $W$ would have to contain some $a \in A$, but this cannot happen because $W \cap A = \emptyset$.

---

Proof that all singletons are closed in a Hausdorff space: let $\{x\}$ be any singleton and $y$ be any other point. Then there is an open neighborhood $U_y$ which contains $y$ but does not contain $x$. Then $$U = \bigcup_{y \in E \setminus \{x\}} U_y$$ is a union of open sets, hence open, and $U$ contains every point of $E$ except $x$, hence $U = \{x\}^c$. Since $\{x\}^c$ is open, it follows that $\{x\}$ is closed.

Comment: please why $W$ is open ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou: In a Hausdorff space, all singletons are open, so $\{x\}$ is an open set. Therefore, $W = V \setminus \{x\} = V \cap (\{x\})^c$ is the intersection of two open sets, hence $W$ is open.

Comment: @Vrouvrou: I added a proof that singletons are closed in a Hausdorff space (or more generally, in any $T1$ space, which is a space where if $x$ and $y$ are disjoint, then there is an open neighborhood of $x$ which does not contain $y$, and vice versa; this is of course true in a Hausdorff space since we can find disjoint open neighborhoods of $x$ and $y$).

Comment: So the main result holds in any $T_1$ space.

Comment: I don't understand $W$ can have similar points with $\overline{A}$ where this points are not in $A$

Comment: @Bungo please i don't understand your proof

Comment: @Vrouvrou:I'm not sure I understand your question. $W$ is defined so it does not intersect $A$, but $\overline A$ is larger than $A$, so we need to verify that $W$ does not intersect $\overline A$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in\left(\overline{A}\right)'$ and let $V$ be an open set with $x\in V$.

Then $(V\setminus\{x\})\cap\overline{A}\neq\varnothing$. Let $y\in(V\setminus\{x\})\cap\overline{A}$.

In order to prove that $x\in A'$ it is enough to show that $(V\setminus\{x\})\cap A\neq\varnothing$.

We will do that by deducing a contradiction on base of the assumption: $(V\setminus\{x\})\cap A=\varnothing$.

Note that $V$ is an open set that contains $y\in\overline{A}$, so that $V\cap A\neq\varnothing$.

$(V\setminus\{x\})\cap A=\varnothing$ combined with $V\cap A\neq\varnothing$ implies $V\cap A=\{x\}$.

We have $y\in V\setminus\{x\}$ so that $y\neq x$.

Let $U$ be an open set with $y\in U$ and $x\notin U$. Such set exists because the space is Hausdorff.

(Actually it is enough allready if the space is T1.)

Then $y\in U\cap V$, $U\cap V$ is open and $(U\cap V)\cap A=\varnothing$.

This contradicts that $y\in\overline{A}$ and we are ready.

Comment: please why you take the same $V$ you must say  that there exist $V_1\in \mathcal{V}_x$ such that $V_1\setminus\{x\})\cap A=\emptyset$

Comment: I am afraid that I do not understand you (especially the words "the same"). I start with on open set $V$ that contains $x$. In your notation probably $V\in\mathcal V_x$. Then it is proved that the assumption $(V\setminus\{x\})\cap A=\varnothing$ leads to a contradiction. Conclusion: $(V\setminus\{x\})\cap A\neq\varnothing$. This for every $V\in\mathcal V_x$ so that $x\in A'$. There is no need to refer to some (other?) $V_1\in\mathcal V_x$.

Comment: It might be that "my" $V$ (neighborhood of $x$) corresponds with "your" $V_1$, and that "my" $U$ (neighborhood of $y$) corresponds with "your" $V_2$.

Comment: I can say this:assume that $x\in \left(\overline{A}\right)'$ and $x\notin A'$ i.e $\forall V\in \mathcal{V}_x, V\setminus\{x\} \cap \overline{A}\neq \emptyset....(1)$ and $\exists V_1\in \mathcal{V}_x, V_1\setminus\{x\}\cap A=\emptyset$ as $(1)$ i true for all $V$ then it is is true for $V_1$ so $V_1\setminus\{x\}\cap \overline{A}\neq\emptyset$ so $\exists y\in V_1\setminus\{x\}\cap \overline{A}$ and find a contradition with $y\in \overline{A}$

Comment: Do you understand my proof? If not, then what is unclear to you?

Comment: i don't understand why you say that $V\setminus\{x\}\cap A=\emptyset$ we mut fix $V$ because $x\notin A'$ means that there exist V not for all V

Comment: Actually I am not **saying** that $V\setminus\{x\}\cap A=\varnothing$, but I am **assuming** that $V\setminus\{x\}\cap A=\varnothing$. Based on that assumption I reduce a contradiction, wich allows me to conclude that the assumption is false, so that $V\setminus\{x\}\cap A\neq\varnothing$ must be true. Exactly what I am after. This is proved for an arbitrary (open) neighborhood of $x$, so it works for *any* neighborhood of $x$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31188/discussion-between-vrouvrou-and-drhab).

Comment: I am waiting for you in the chatroom.

Comment: I have been waiting in vain.